# How to mock static methods using UnitilsJUnit4?

Tags: java, mocking, static-methods, unitils

I have method `getAllCustomers` inside `CustomerService` class. Inside this method I call another static method from `CustomerDao` class.
Now when I am writing the junit for method `getAllCustomers` inside `customerService` class, where I want to mock the call to
static method of `CustomerDao` i.e. `getAllCustomers`. Here is the brief code snippet of method `getAllCustomers` inside
`CustomerService` class. **Is it possible to mock the static method call using unitils?**

```
Public static List<CustomerDate> getAllCustomers()
{
//some operations
List<CustomerDate> customers=CustomerDao.getAllCustomers();// static method inside CustomerDao
//some operations
}
```

Above code is just an example I am trying to put. Please avoid the discussion why these methods are designed as static
methods. That's a separate story .)

Comment: This is as good an example why not to use static methods in a TDD environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt whether it can be achieved with unitils.
But please consider using [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) instead which seems to be capable of handling what you need. It can mock static methods,private methods and more (Ref: [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/))

Answer (score 0):

This would be a matter of:

- Setting up the mock
- Calling the mock and expecting some data back
- Verifying the end result of your call given your data

So, without really much ado about the static call, here's the way you can set it up in PowerMock:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(CustomerDao.class)
public class CustomerTest {

    @Test
    public void testCustomerDao() {
        PowerMock.mockStatic(CustomerDao.class);
        List<CustomerDate> expected = new ArrayList<CustomerDate>();
        // place a given data value into your list to be asserted on later
        expect(CustomerDao.getAllCustomers()).andReturn(expected);
        replay(CustomerDao.class);
        // call your method from here
        verify(CustomerDao.class);
        // assert expected results here
    }
}
```

Comment: Tanks Makoto. Is there a way we can do similar thing in Unitils?

Comment: I've only ever seen it with PowerMock.  Typically one avoids making certain objects (such as this) static, as it does make them slightly harder to test.